# Why I get error when call method from controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create an object of class in current class:

```
 CustomTableViewController * dController = [[CustomTableViewController init] alloc];

[dController getItemsByCategory:@"3" andCategory:@"4"];
```

After this I get error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[CustomTableViewController<0x102b35298> init]: cannot init a class object.'
```

`CustomTableViewController` is:

```
    @implementation CustomTableViewController

    - (instancetype)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            // TODO
        }

        return self;
    }

  - (void) getItemsByCategory: (NSString*) id andCategory:(NSString*)     category {

       // TODO
    }

    }
```

Also I have declared function `getItemsByCategory` in `.h` file

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the methods in the wrong order here:

```
 CustomTableViewController * dController = [[CustomTableViewController init] alloc]
```

Change to

```
 CustomTableViewController * dController = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] init]
```

Answer (score 1):

### [As already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370795/2976878), you're simply calling these methods in the wrong order.

However, I think it's worth knowing *why* what you're doing is fundamentally incorrect.

- `alloc` is a **static** method. It can *only* be called on a **class**, not an instance (`CustomTableViewController` **not** `CustomTableViewController *`). What it does is *allocate* the memory for your instance, and will return a new **instance** of your class.
- `init` is an **instance** method. It can *only* be called on an **instance**, not a class (`CustomTableViewController *` **not** `CustomTableViewController`). What it does is *initialise* your instance, by performing basic setup, and will return that *initialised* instance.

Therefore, calling `init` on a **class** makes absolutely no sense fundamentally, as there's no memory to perform the initial setup in to begin with.

**It's the programming equivalent of trying to put objects in a box, before the box exists.**